# Laravel selected item by javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

When we have html select in laravel we will add code below and it returns database value as selected item:

```
{{ $category->id == $product->category_id ? 'selected' : '' }}
```

like:

```
<select class="form-control" name="category_id">
  @foreach($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == $product->category_id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->title }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

That's perfect if we use html select but now i am using ajax select and returning data's and i can't get what is set in database as selected option.

here is my codes:

`html`

```
<div class="mt-20">
  {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Category') }}
  <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
     <option value="">Select Category</option>
       @foreach($categories as $category)
         <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == $product->category_id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->title }}</option>
       @endforeach
  </select>
</div>

<!-- sub category -->
<div class="mt-20">
  {{ Form::label('subcategory_id', 'Sub Category') }}
  <select class="form-control" name="subcategory_id">
    <option value="">Select Sub Category</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

`javascripts`

```
<!-- subcategory -->
<script>
  jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('select[name="category_id"]').on('change', function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });
       var CategoryId = $(this).val();
        if(CategoryId) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '{{ url('admin/subcategorylists') }}/'+encodeURI(CategoryId),
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {
                $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty();
                var options = data.map(function(state) {
                    return $("<option class='form-control'>").val(state.id)
                                        .text(state.title);
                });
                $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty().append(options);
              }
            });
        }else{
          $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty().append("<option class='form-control' value='' selected>Select</option>");
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

## Question

1. As my codes are in edit page, I need to get my subcategory select
   `with default selected option` (which is the value saved in database),
   **how do i do that?**

Answer (score 1):

Just set the value of `select` tag to what you get from database. Like

```
$('select[name="subcategory_id"]').val("yourValue");
```

Comment: my value is include 2 parts `id` and `title` of subcategory, shouldn't i use append? if not can you tell me which i have to put as `.val()`?

Comment: @mafortis: try with `id`!

Comment: I just added a dummy value. You can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: doesn't return anything

Comment: what does not return ? how do you know which value to select ? it would be in some variable right ? pass that variable to `.val()`

Comment: see i'm a bit confuse here, i have `2` `$('select[name="subcategory_id"]')` which one you mean i should change? the one with `.empty();` in the end or the one has `.append(options);` ?

Comment: Go with this: `$('select[name="subcategory_id"]').val(state.id);`

Comment: just put this line after `$('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty().append(options);`

Comment: plus. you're already removing options in success callback. No need to do it one more time here `$('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty().append(options);` `->  $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').append(options);`

Comment: I remove it in case user select diffident category, subcategories of old category will be disappear.

Comment: not sure why, but somehow i don't get the result by your way. :/

Answer (score 0):

On your ajax request you are expecting response data in json format as per your  code.

```
dataType: "json",
```

Now if you are going to see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) data must in array format.

```
Array.map()
```

So I guess if you are going to look on console you'll notice the error

```
Error: data.map is not a function
```

Try to use [.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) of jQuery instead.
change this block of code:
From:

```
var options = data.map(function(state) {
    return $("<option class='form-control'>").val(state.id)
                        .text(state.title);
});
```

To:

```
var options = $.map(data, function(state) {
    return $("<option class='form-control'>").val(state.id)
                        .text(state.title);
});
```

Hope it helps!